# tensorflow gradient in custom functions

Tags: tensorflow

I want to use deep learning to solve a well-known inverse problem in geophysics. The network input is "d" *the measurements* and the output is "m" *the resistivity model*. Of course, The typical loss function will involve just an MSE with the outputs such as MSE(m, m_pred). Still, because it is a physical problem, I should include a data-response regularization such as d_pred=F[m_pred], where "F" is the forward modeling operator. This, my loss function is
[image]

the forward operator is defined as:

```
import math
import cmath
import time
from scipy import constants
#start = time.clock();
# Please check the Magnetic Permeability (H/m)
# at: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/constants.html#module-scipy.constants
mu = constants.mu_0; #Magnetic Permeability (H/m)

# forward modelling operator F[m] = d

def MTforwardModel(resistivities,thicknesses,frequencies):
  n = len(resistivities);
  apparentResistivity=[]
  phase=[]
  for frequency in frequencies:
      w =  2*math.pi*frequency;
      impedances = list(range(n));
      #compute basement impedance
      impedances[n-1] = np.sqrt(w*mu*resistivities[n-1]*1j);

      for j in range(n-2,-1,-1):
          resistivity = resistivities[j];
          thickness = thicknesses[j];

          # 3. Compute apparent resistivity from top layer impedance
          # Step 2. Iterate from bottom layer to top(not the basement)
          # Step 2.1 Calculate the intrinsic impedance of current layer
          dj = np.sqrt((w * mu * (1.0/resistivity))*1j);
          wj = dj * resistivity;
          # Step 2.2 Calculate Exponential factor from intrinsic impedance
          ej = np.exp(-2*thickness*dj);

          # Step 2.3 Calculate reflection coeficient using current layer
          #          intrinsic impedance and the below layer impedance
          belowImpedance = impedances[j + 1];
          rj = (wj - belowImpedance)/(wj + belowImpedance);
          re = rj*ej;
          Zj = wj * ((1 - re)/(1 + re));
          impedances[j] = Zj;

      # Step 3. Compute apparent resistivity from top layer impedance
      Z = impedances[0];
      absZ = abs(Z);
      #apparentResistivity.append((absZ * absZ)/(mu * w))
      #phase.append(math.atan2(Z.imag, Z.real))
      phase.append(absZ)
  return np.array(phase)#(np.array(apparentResistivity),np.array(phase))
```

Note that *resistivities* are the network's output. here is the [colab implementation](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ZHujgs55Ydtdxf0TKiN2xXrLD4w_o-5-?usp=sharing) for reproducibility. When I just want to use the forward modeling term (blue term) I got **ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable**. I suspect it is because at some point inside the forward modeling, the network is disconnected from the outputs, and then gradients are not able to be calculated with respect to the layers.

My questions are:

> How should I write the forward operator in order to be used by the loss function and gradients during the neural network training ?

> Even if now is not working the gradients from the blue term, I am able to calculate that term, so, if I add the black and the blue term, the loss term is taking into account during the error backpropagation and weights updating?

Comment: Tensorflow records the operations in order to compute gradients of variables with backpropagation. I advise to read the documentation about [automatic differentiation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/autodiff). Maybe the problem is that you are using numpy operations which meaning that your Tensor "escapes" Tensorflow tracing. So the operations applied to your Tensor are not recorded, and the gradient are 0 or NULL. So you should try to translate your 'numpy' function to something closer to tensorflow using the maximum of TF preimplemented functions.

Comment: @LMaxime you are right, I used only tensor operations and now it is working very well.